# Proving that $ab+cd \leqslant \sqrt{a^2+c^2} \sqrt{b^2+d^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

> Let $a, b, c$ and $d$ be real numbers. Show that $$ab+cd \leqslant \sqrt{a^2+c^2} \sqrt{b^2+d^2}.$$When does equality hold?

So if $ab+cd < 0$ the solution is trivial. I was curious if one could use something like Cauchy–Schwarz here? I don't see a direct approach, but perhaps I'm not that familiar with it yet.

Comment: This is a direct application of C-S inequality and the condition for equality is also standard.  You could use Wikipedia  if you are not familiar with the inequality.

Comment: Thanks! @KaviRamaMurthy. I guess it's the square roots that are confusing me.

Comment: This is precisely Cauchy-Schwarz. Equality iff the vectors $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: This *is* Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity)  $(ab+cd)^2+(ad-bc)^2 = (a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$

Answer (score 1):

$$P={a, c}, Q={b,d}$$

C-S states that having $2$ sequences, namely $A$ and $B$,

$$(\sum A_iB_i)^2 \leq (\sum(A_i))^2 \cdot (\sum(B_i))^2$$
By C-S,

$$(ab+cd)^2  \leq  (a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$$

Take square root on both sides and you have the desired inequality

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a, b, c, d$ are positive, you can divide through by $ab$ and get

$$1+\frac{cd}{ab} \leq \sqrt{1+\frac{c^2}{a^2}} \sqrt{1+\frac{d^2}{b^2}}.$$

Let $x=\frac{c}{a}$ and $y=\frac{d}{b}$ and square both sides:

$$1+2xy + x^2y^2 \leq 1+x^2+y^2+x^2y^2$$

or

$$2xy\leq x^2 + y^2.$$

Divide  by $x^2$ to get

$$2\frac{y}{x} \leq 1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2$$

Let $z = \frac{y}{x}$:

$$2z \leq 1+z^2$$

or

$$0 \leq z^2-2z+1 = (z-1)^2$$

which always holds.  Since all the steps are reversible, this proves the inequality.  Plus, you can see that equality happens exactly when $z=1$, that is when $x=y$, that is when $ad = bc$.

Comment: never seen a proof for C-S for the case of two number in this way. Thanks for this. :) The notation is very clean.

Answer (score 0):

$$(ab+cd)^2\le(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)$$ because

$$a^2b^2+2abcd+c^2\le a^2b^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+c^2d^2$$
from
$$0\le a^2d^2-2abcd+b^2c^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

A standard way to remember C-S (which this inequality exactly is) will be by using vectors: Let $x=(a,c)$ and $y=(b,d)$ be vectors in $\mathbb R^2$, then $ab+cd=x\cdot y$ and $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\sqrt{b^2+d^2}=|x||y|$ is the product of their lengths. Now, it is a standard fact that $x\cdot y=|x||y|\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $y$, so the result follows from the fact that $|\!\cos\theta|\leq 1$.

This argument also works in higher dimensions, but it is not usually regarded as a proof because C-S is often used in defining the notion of an angle in $\mathbb R^n$ especially for $n\geq 4$, so we are at risk of a circular argument.